# PHP if comparison vs MySQL Where (Which is more efficient)

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, comparison

**My situation:** My website will look at a cookie for a remember me token and a user ID. If the cookie exists it will unhash it and look up the user ID and compare the token. with a "WHERE userid = '' and rememberme = ''".

**My question is**: Will MySQL optimize this query on the unique userid so that the query does not scan the entire database for this 20+ character token? Or instead  should I just select the token from the database and then use a **php** `if` comparison to check if the tokens are the same?

**In short (tl;dr):** Would it be better to check if a token matches in with a MySQL select query, or to grab all the tokens from a databases database and compare the values with a **php** `if` conditional?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a bad question, but I think you could write a simple test to find out yourself!

Comment: is `userid` indexed?

Comment: It really depends on the rest of the query, but assuming a relatively simple SELECT, with no JOINs or subqueries; then as long as user_id is indexed, and rememberme is not (or is a latter field on the same index), then yes, MySQL will almost assuredly optimize it in the way you are hoping. (Technically, if rememberme is indexed and the hash is well distributed, it still won't need to do a full table scan.)

Comment: userid is the primary key, unique, indexed. The rest of the query would be checking if banned =1 otherwise its just that.

Comment: @Incognito in your case it would be faster to use the database IF you have a lot of rows, check out my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple answer:**

YES, the database will definitely optimism your search AS LONG AS THE variable you are searching in the `WHERE ...` portion is indexed! You definitely should not retrieve all the information via SQL and then do a PHP conditional if you are worried about performance.

So if the `id` column in your table is not indexed, you should index it. If you have let say... 1 million rows already in your table and run a command like `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 994321`, you would see a definite increase in performance.

**Elaborating:**

A database (like MySQL) is made to be much faster at executing queries/commands than you would expect that to happen in php for instance. In your specific situation, lets say you are executing this SQL statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 4";
```

If you have 1 million users, and the `id` column is not indexed, MySQL will look through all 1 million users to find all the rows with `id = 4`. However, if it is indexed, there is something called a `b tree` that MySQL makes (**behind the scenes**) which works similarly to how the indexing of a dictionary work.

If you try to find the world **slowly** in a dictionary, you might open the book in the middle, find words that start with the letter **M** and then look in the middle again of the pages on your right side hoping to find a letter closer to **S**. This method of looking for a word is much faster than looking at each single page from the beginning 1 by 1.

For that very reason, MySQL has created indexes to help performance and this feature should definitely be taken advantage of to help increase the speed of your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing it on MySQL-side should be fast. It should find the corresponding row by ID first (fast) and then compare the hash (also fast, since there will be only 1 row to check).

Try analyzing the query with [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to find out the actual execution plan.

Comment: Thanks, EXPLAIN showed that it uses the key "Primary" so I assume that means it's using userid as the main index. Which only leaves one row to compare. Seems the MySQL is the best bet then.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it will be always faster to use WHERE clause no matter what (real) database server will be used. Database engines have strong algorithms for searching data written in language that is compiling to low-level code dedicated to platform, so it cannot be even compared with some loop written in interpreted PHP.
And remember that for PHP loop you will have to send all records from DB to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you Data Base its on a separate server than you Apache PHP there is not doubt it would be faster if you write a query in MySQL.

If your PHP and MySQL server is on the same physical server probably PHP would be faster cause the comparison will be made on the RAM But have all the User Id array into RAM would be a waste of RAM so you can use Indexes that would speed up your query

ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX idx__tableName__fieldName (field)